# Run block until condition is met JS

Tags: javascript, while-loop

So I have a function that is passed an element. Then I wish to run a series of functions until one of the functions returns a value other than false.

The behaviour I experience is that the while loop is always completed at least once, and so only the value from the last function is being returned. Any suggestions? I would like to use the while loop format if possible.

```
function data_can_be_extracted(element) {      

 try {
        let data = false
        let one_iteration_complete = false        
       
    while (!(data) && !(one_iteration_complete)) {

            data = function_a(element)

            data = function_b(element)

            data = function_c(element)

            data = function_d(element)

            one_iteration_complete = true

        }
        return option
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to stop the loop based on the return value of `function_x` then you need to check the value of `function_x` in-line and `break`. Alternatively you could do something like `data = function_a(e) || function_b(e) || etc` and rely on expr short-circuiting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was trying to make it easier for readability but if it's not an option then that's no hassle thanks

Comment: traditionally, ```break```  will break the loop on most programming languages, even JS.

Comment: @beautysleep Not sure what's unreadable about the short-circuit version.

Comment: It just felt cluttered on the screen, I am going with data = function_a(e) || function_b(e) || etc as you said, it's the shortest by far.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
function data_can_be_extracted(element) {      
 try {
        let data = false       
    do {
            data = () => {return false} || () => {return true} || () => {return true} || () => {return true}
        } while(!data)
        return option
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can use your functions in place of arrow functions I used and instead of meeting one run condition, you can use do/while loop.